# Translate C# type param to VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to translate this C# code to VB.net

```
public List<T> BinaryFileDeSerialize<T>(string filePath) where T : class
```

But I don't know how to the  would look like in vb.net

I tried it like this:

```
Public Function BinaryFileDeSerialize(ByVal filePath As String) As List(Of T)
```

But I'm getting an error saying that the `T` in `List(Of T)` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're missing the generic type in method declaration. You can't return `T` without defining it earlier.

```
Public Function BinaryFileDeSerialize(Of T As { Class })(ByVal filePath As String) As List(Of T)
```

Comment: Change `As List(Of T)` to `As T` and that's it.

Comment: No need for the curly braces in this case.